# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate

Tags: python, error-handling, pytorch, runtime

I am trying to run a pytorch code with jupyter notebook and I got this error

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 2.00 GiB total capacity; 1.23 GiB already allocated; 18.83 MiB free; 1.25 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I had already find answer. and most of all say just reduce the batch size.
I have tried reduce the batch size from 20 to 10 to 2 and 1. Right now still can't run the code

My GPU is Quadro p620

Comment: What model are you using and what's the input size? 2GB of GPU memory won't be enough for any complex models, especially for tasks that require bigger input sizes.

Comment: @MichaelJungo I'm using this model https://github.com/alterzero/RBPN-PyTorch/blob/master/main.py (Video Super-resolution) My input size is " torch.Size([2, 3, 64, 64]) "

Comment: Even though the input is rather small, the super resolution will end up using more memory as it's increasing the size. I don't think that 2GB are enough to train that model. If you just want to use the pre-trained model, you should make sure to disable gradients, either by setting [`torch.set_grad_enabled(False)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_grad_enabled) or by using the [`torch.no_grad` context manager](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.no_grad). Otherwise, you will unfortunately have to run it on the CPU.

Comment: Try using a batch size of 1. If it still doesn't fit, then might not be possible with 64, 64 input size. Maybe try using Google Colab (if you're just testing) since it gives 8 or 11 GB GPUs.

Comment: @akshayk07 I just have change my GPU to RTX2080 (8GB) I still get this error CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 6.02 GiB already allocated; 1.25 MiB free; 6.03 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Comment: @S.Xu check [this issue](https://github.com/alterzero/RBPN-PyTorch/issues/12) in the GitHub repo you mention. They say to use smaller patch size (48) and lesser nFrames (5). Maybe this might help. Also, maybe going through other issues might help (and you can even open your own issue).

Answer (score -1):

You can free up the existing memory by

```
nvidia-smi
```

note the process and kill using

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

PS: Please the process before killing it!. This solution worked for me when i tried to run large model and it was still kept on running after stopping it. **DON'T KILL THE MODEL WHICH IS ONGOING TRAINING!**